# How To wrap Text while using PdfContentByte in itextsharp

Tags: itext

I used PdfContentByte to show text in pdf in that i also used SetTextMatrix mathod for postion of that text now when my text is large it will not show in pdf show can i wrap the text show i can able to see it below is my code

```
PdfContentByte cb = myPDFWriter.DirectContent;
cb.BeginText();
BaseFont bf_qty123 = BaseFont.CreateFont(BaseFont.TIMES_ROMAN, BaseFont.CP1252, false);
cb.SetFontAndSize(bf_qty123, 10f);
cb.SetTextMatrix(422,100);
cb.ShowText("longstring");
cb.EndText();
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

use Column like this :

```
Dim p As Phrase = New Phrase("your txt", FontFactory.GetFont(BaseFont.HELVETICA, BaseFont.CP1250, True, fsize)) 
Dim ct As New ColumnText(cb) 
ct.SetSimpleColumn(p, x, y, ux, uy, 10, Element.ALIGN_LEFT)
ct.Go()
```

and fix width hight bloc ux, uy

see this also :

[How to position and wrap long text?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2755621/itextsharp-how-to-position-and-wrap-long-text)

Comment: Not sure why this was downvoted, this is nearly identical to the code I use to wrap text in my project.